# C++11 parallel for implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

First of all I made a thread pool, and tried to do some heavy arithmetic operations on an  array with a size of 40960 float elements.

A single-threaded approach got a result of 0.0009 second, while a paralleled approach with 4 threads running synchronously got 0.0003 second. In this implementation, I manually distributed the task into 4 parts and queued them into the thread pool.

Now I want to provide a general method `parfor` for my thread pool. I tried this:

```
    void parfor(int begin, int end, std::function<void(int)>func)
    {
        int delta = (end - begin) / M_count;
        for (int i = 0; i < M_count; ++i)
            queue([=]{
                int localbegin = begin + i*delta;
                int localend = (i == M_count - 1) ? end : localbegin + delta;
                for (int it = localbegin; it < localend; ++it)
                    func(it);
            });
        wait();
    }
```

Where M_count is the number of threads. And the execution time becomes 0.003 sec (about 10 times of the one with its job manually distributed). I guess std::function have a great runtime overhead but don't know any other alternative approach. Could you give me some advice? Many thanks.

Edit:
According to Rapptz's advice, I tried this:

```
template <typename Function>
void parfor(int begin, int end, Function)
```

And used it like this:

```
pool.parfor(0, 40960, [&](int i){
    buff[i] = pow5(buff[i]);
});
```

It shows some errors:

```
error C2371: 'it' : redefinition; different basic types 
error C2512: 'wmain::<lambda_badf06dfbebc4bb15b3ade2b922c7f76>' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

I think it treats the lambda as a type but don't know how to solve it...

Comment: Probably your manual version could inline the function, while `parfor` obviously cannot.

Comment: Use a template instead of `std::function`.

Comment: @woolstar Yeah I guess so. But don't know how to force a function inline in my parfor.

Comment: @Rapptz I guess I can have something like `template <class Ret, class... Arg>`. But actually nothing other than `void(int)` makes sense here...

Comment: No, just do `template<typename Function>`.

Comment: @Rapptz Eh. Does it mean `template <typename Function> void parfor(int begin, int end, Function)`?

Comment: Rapptz's suggestion's probably best.  Marking the function `inline` may do the trick to, but given it's only a compiler hint it may not be reliable.

Comment: @TonyD I tried it but ran into some errors... Please see my edit.

Comment: Errors look like you've broken the syntax of the function call, we need the full `parfor` to help figure out how.

Comment: @Casey I've found the reason. It's because `Function` is a type and I called it directly...

Comment: How much time does it take for pow5(buff[i]); ? If it is very less then the time it takes to create threads would be significant than the actual work itself.

Comment: @Jagannath Hi. I found 40960 is not that big an array so after increasing it to 409600, the advantage of threading became obvious:)

Comment: Just being curious, have you tried intel tbb::parallel_for? I am suspecting it is not your lambda problem but something else.

Comment: @XiaogeSu Nope... Because I'm practicing and this is just a toy:) Thanks for you advice and if I have to use it in real I will try that well designed implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too much for a comment...)  This is just explaining how to implement Rapptz's suggestion of using a template parameter to specify the function (so it can be inlined).

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int n) { std::cout << "f(" << n << ");\n"; }
void g(int n) { std::cout << "g(" << n << ");\n"; }

template <typename Function>
void t(Function function, int n)
{
    static int x;
    std::cout << "&x " << &x << '\n';
    function(n);
}

struct FuncF { static void f(int n) { std::cout << "Ff(" << n << ");\n"; } };
struct FuncG { static void f(int n) { std::cout << "Gf(" << n << ");\n"; } };

template <typename Function>
void ft(int n)
{
    static int x;
    std::cout << "&x " << &x << '\n';
    Function::f(n);
}

int main()
{
    t(f, 42);
    t(g, 42);

    ft<FuncF>(42);
    ft<FuncG>(42);
}
```

This prints something like:

```
&x 00421760
f(42);
&x 00421760
g(42);
&x 00421764
Ff(42);
&x 00421768
Gf(42);
```

Note that the first two print the same address for `x`... that's because only one instantiation of the template is needed as the function type is the same for both calls.  The `ft` template uses the template parameter to access the function without having a run-time function argument involved, so there are two instantiations yielding different addresses for the local static `x`.

To get your function calls inlined, you should adopt an approach similar to `FuncF`/`FuncG` and `ft`.

Comment: Thank you! This is so brilliant and it works! I just recalled this is something like functor...  But what makes me upset is the single threaded code runs faster than my parfor under release...

Comment: @babel92: well, 40960 isn't a lot of floats, and 0.0009 is a tough time to beat after thread startup/synchronisation.  You might get much better results if you're able to use CPU or GPU instructions for parallel real-number processing (I've never used them, but think there were some introduced with the MMX and/or SSE CPU instruction set additions).

Comment: After increasing the array to 409600, the advantage of threading became obvious:) In fact this is just a experiment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @babel92: yup - bigger batches the better.  You're welcome.  Cheers.

Comment: Note that in `t`, you are printing the address of `n` not `x`.